# How to Aggregate MongoDB Collections using C# Classes

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is a highly simplified example where I have three collections of classes (`Team`, `League`, `Player`) in separate collections in MongoDB. I am using the C# MongoDB Driver in a .NET 8 Blazor Server App.

Data for each of these objects may be updating independently, and these objects can be used in multiple instances of the other classes. So I am trying to avoid storing all of the data in a single document collection for Team.

I'm currently storing the `Team` in the database using the `TeamData` class below (`IMongoCollection<TeamData>`). However, when I go to retrieve the `TeamData` from the database I would like it to be the fully realized `Team` class.

I don't know how to get this data to "join" when I get these from the database using aggregateasync. I'm looking for help on how to use the MongoDB C# Driver to get these from the database as fully realized classes. All of the examples I've seen require a lot of "magic string" data, instead of using the classes and class data that's already in my code.

I feel like the line at the bottom in the GetAllTeams method is where I'm stuck.

```
public class Player
{
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int Handicap { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set }
}

public class Team
{
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    public League League { get; set; }

    public Player Player1 { get; set; }

    public Player Player2 { get; set; }
}

// this is how I am currently storing the data for the team in the database, where I have references to the other objects.
public Class TeamData
{
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string LeagueId { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Player1Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Player2Id { get; set; }
}

public async Task<List<Team>> GetAllTeams()
{
    IMongoCollection<TeamData> teamCollection = Database.GetCollection<TeamData>("Teams");
    IMongoCollection<League> leagueCollection = Database.GetCollection<League>("Leagues");
    IMongoCollection<Player> playerCollection = Database.GetCollection<Player>("Players");

    var result = teamCollection.FindAsync(_ => true).AggregateAsync(what needs to go here to make this work);

    return result.ToList();
}
```

For context, this is how I am doing this today, but this feels highly verbose and inefficient.

```
public override async Task<List<Team>> GetAllAsync()
{
    IMongoCollection<TeamData> teamCollection = Database.GetCollection<TeamData>("Teams"_
    IMongoCollection<League> leagues = Database.GetCollection<League>("Leagues");
    IMongoCollection<Player> players = Database.GetCollection<Player>("Players");

    var data = await teamCollection.FindAsync(_ => true);

    List<Team> teams = [];

    foreach (TeamData t in data.ToList())
    {
        teams.Add(new Team()
        {
            Id = t.Id,
            Number = t.Number,
            League = (await leagues.FindAsync(l => l.Id == t.LeagueId)).First(),
            Player1 = (await players.FindAsync(p => p.Id == t.Player1Id)).First(),
            Player2 = (await players.FindAsync(p => p.Id == t.Player2Id)).First(),
        });
    }

    return teams;
}
```

Comment: `var result = teamCollection.FindAsync(_ => true).AggregateAsync(what needs to go here to make this work);` - this code doesn't work. Aggregate can be called only on the collection level

Comment: "Join" like functionality can be archived via `Lookup`, however it's not direct equivalent

Comment: The other question I would ask, is there anything wrong with the way I am doing this now, in the bottom of the post?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a lookup join with multiple collections via the LINQ query expression which I think is the easiest way.

**Approach 1: LINQ query expression**

```cs
var data = (from team in teamCollection.AsQueryable()
            join league in leagues.AsQueryable() on team.LeagueId equals league.Id
            join player1 in players.AsQueryable() on team.Player1Id equals player1.Id
            join player2 in players.AsQueryable() on team.Player2Id equals player2.Id
            select new Team
            {
                Id = team.Id,
                League = league,
                Number = team.Number,
                Player1 = player1,
                Player2 = player2,
            }).ToList();
```

---

Alternatively, you can write the aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection('Teams').aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Leagues',
        localField: 'LeagueId',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'Leagues'
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Players',
        localField: 'Player1Id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'PlayerOnes'
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'Players',
        localField: 'Player2Id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'PlayerTwos'
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 1,
        Number: 1,
        League: { $first: '$Leagues' },
        Player1: { $first: '$PlayerOnes' },
        Player2: { $first: '$PlayerTwos' }
      }
    }
  ]
);
```

**Approach 2: Aggregation pipeline with `BsonDocument`**

```cs
var data = await teamCollection.Aggregate<Team>(new BsonDocument[]
    {
        new BsonDocument("$lookup",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "from", "Leagues" },
                    { "localField", "LeagueId" },
                    { "foreignField", "_id" },
                    { "as", "Leagues" }
                }),
        new BsonDocument("$lookup",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "from", "Players" },
                    { "localField", "Player1Id" },
                    { "foreignField", "_id" },
                    { "as", "PlayerOnes" }
                }),
        new BsonDocument("$lookup",
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "from", "Players" },
                    { "localField", "Player2Id" },
                    { "foreignField", "_id" },
                    { "as", "PlayerTwos" }
                }),
        new BsonDocument("$project",
            new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", 1 },
                { "Number", 1 },
                { "League",
                    new BsonDocument("$first", "$Leagues") },
                { "Player1",
                    new BsonDocument("$first", "$PlayerOnes") },
                { "Player2",
                    new BsonDocument("$first", "$PlayerTwos") }
            })
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: this is correct answer, I will just add that the c# code in the last example can be written in typed form too since there are typed forms for $lookup (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.21/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluent_1_Lookup__2.htm) and $project (https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.21/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IAggregateFluent_1_Project__1.htm)

Comment: So this second approach is what I see in all of the documentation, using the BsonDocument. What I'm unfamiliar with is how to transform this into Team, League and Player. I'll look at the first approach as it feels more like what I was looking for in terms of using defined classes.

Comment: @Jeremy, see links in my comment above